# Bounded Checkbox not firing event

Tags: wpf, events, binding

I have a check box where the property ischecked is bounded to another checkbox. In the resources block i've set a style that sets the event triger for a checkbox. Here's the code:

```
<Style x:Key="cbClickEvent" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
   <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="CheckBox_Click"/>
</Style>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
   <CheckBox x:Name="cbAll" Content=" All" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
   <CheckBox Content=" MyCB" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=cbAll, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource cbClickEvent}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

When i click the checkbox MyCB the event is triggered, but not when i clicked the checkbox All. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you click on the "All" checkbox the value gets transfered to the "MyCB" checkbox via binding. But in the style you subscribe to the `Click`event which obviously is not firing in this case because you don't actually click on the "MyCB" checkbox (you click on "All").

What you can do is, instead of subscribing to the `Click` event, you can subscribe to the `Checked` and `Unchecked` events:

```
<EventSetter Event="Checked" Handler="CheckBox_Checked"/>
<EventSetter Event="Unchecked" Handler="CheckBox_Unchecked"/>
```

Comment: This won't make it work either, the problem is that he's not setting the Style to the cbAll CheckBox, even if he adds a handler to the Checked and Unchecked events, they still won't get fired if he doesn't first sets the Style to the cbAll CheckBox.

Comment: @Carlo - When you click the "All" checkbox the value (`IsChecked`) will be transfered to the `IsChecked` of the "MyCB" via binding. And because the `IsChecked` value is changed the `Checked`/`Unchecked` events will fire on the "MyCB" checkbox (where the style is applied) so the handlers will be executed.

Comment: Yeah, I hear ya, but IsChecked has nothing to do with the Click event. You can check and uncheck and the click event will get fired regardless (of course check and uncheck by clicking). What you are saying is that if he subscribed to the Checked and Unchecked event, then the Checked and Unchecked handler will get fired on botch CheckBoxes simultaneously (because the IsChecked property is bound). But if you look closer, the cbAll is not subscribed to the Click event (nor will be to the Checked and Unchecked events) if the style is not set properly, which in this case, it isn't.

Comment: @Carlo - Once again. You don't need to subscribe to any events on the "All" checkbox. Events on "MyCB" checkbox will fire because 'IsChecked` value will change (because of binding). Here is what happens: Click "All" -> "All".IsChecked changed -> "MyCB".IsChecked changed (binding) -> "MyCB".Checked/Unchecked raised -> CheckBox_Checked/Unchecked executed.

Comment: Your proposed solution worked perfectly. What i've change in my solution is the handler, i'm only using one handler for both events.

Answer (score 0):

2 possible solitions:

1) Add the

```
Style="{StaticResource cbClickEvent}"
```

To the cbAll CheckBox

2) Remove that line from the MyCB CheckBox and remove the x:Key property from the style. It will look like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="CheckBox_Click"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
    <CheckBox x:Name="cbAll"
              Content=" All"
              VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <CheckBox Content=" MyCB"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=cbAll, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```